# What is the fastest, free Weighted SAT solver?

Tags: logic, graph-theory, computational-complexity, satisfiability

I want to solve the minimum vertex cover problem by solving and equivalent SAT instance. I tried several solvers, but I didn't find any solver which does weighted SAT. Do you know of any free SAT solvers which could do that?

Comment: Since you ask about software, I think your question is more relevant to https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ , or even 
https://stackoverflow.com so you can ask it there or even flag your question and to ask a moderator to move your question there.